# Integrate Facebook Sign In in Intel XDK

Tags: facebook

hope that some body answer.. thanks in advance

I trying to integrate Facebook Sign In in Intel XDK but I only gets a blank screen and a button Cancel on top... any help here is my code

```
function facebook_login(){
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.login",function(e){ 
    if (e.success == true) 
    { 
        var facebookUserID = "me";  //me = the user currently logged into Facebook
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response",function(e) {
            console.log("Facebook User Friends Data Returned");
            if (e.success == true) {
                    var data = e.data.data;
                    var outHTML = "";

                    for (var r=0; r< data.length; r++) {
                    outHTML += "<img src='http://graph.facebook.com/" 
                              + data[r]["id"] 
                              + "/picture' info='" 
                              + data[r]["name"] + "' />";
                    }
                    alert(outHTML);
                    document.removeEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.request.response");
            } 
        },false);
    } 
    else
    { 
        console.log("Unsuccessful Login"); 
    } 
}, false); 
intel.xdk.facebook.login("publish_stream, publish_actions, offline_access");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but if you look at the end of this page : https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/integrating-facebook-functionality-into-hybrid-apps-using-the-intel-xdk
You'll see that you need to register your app through facebook and then build it.
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

The intel.xdk.facebook library only works in the Legacy Builds that can be generated from the XDK IDE. It will not work in the XDK emulator, AppPreview, or Cordova Builds. Below is the forum link where IntelJohn points this out. I have confirmed this with independent testing.

https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=6444&sid=5b50fedfdfcb924a3f69579af01285c1

If your application will rely on any Cordova plugins (meaning you'll have to use the Cordova build) it would be better for you to drop use of the intel.xdk.facebook library and install the Cordova Facebook Plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

Comment: We have tried and tried but all of our builds fail with the cardova plugin